# How to create a vertical line of elements

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to create a vertical like of (in This case 5) elements every time the previous 5 have passed the center of the stage.
But what Im doing is for every element that has passed the center i create 5 new.
So in the 1st moment i have 1 element.

when he passes the center i have 5

when they pass the center i have 5 for every one of those 5 (makes a total of 25)
but they have the same X and Y position and they over stack and look like there are only 5 new

when they pass the center i have 5 for every one of those 25 (makes a lot more than what i want (and i want just 5)) they too over stack

How do I do it that I only add 5 in a new column ??

so far I have this code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    private var myVertArray:Array = new Array();

    private var _box:Box = new Box();

    public function Main()
    {
        _box.x = stage.stageWidth - _box.width;
        _box.y = stage.stageHeight - 200;
        this.addChild(_box);
        myVertArray.push(_box);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame);
    }

    private function onEveryFrame(ev:Event):void
    {
        var _myItem:Box
        for (var i:int = 0; i < myVertArray.length; i++)
        {
            _myItem = myVertArray[i]
            _myItem.x -= 3;

            if(_myItem.x < stage.stageWidth/2 && !_myItem.passedCenter )
            {
                trace("myVertArray.length is : " + myVertArray.length)
                _myItem.passedCenter = true
                for(var j:int = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var _myNewItem:Box = new Box();
                    _myNewItem.x = stage.stageWidth - 40;
                    _myNewItem.y = stage.stageHeight - (_myNewItem.height * j)  -  (j * 5) - _myNewItem.height /2 ;
                    _myNewItem.alpha = 0.2;
                    this.addChild(_myNewItem);
                    myVertArray.push(_myNewItem)
                }
            }
        }

        if(_myItem.x < 0)
        {
            removeChild(_myItem);
            myVertArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

}
```

and in the **Box()** class is just a simple rectangle movieClip in which i also have

```
public var passedCenter:Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need give only one object in column ability to create new column. You could do it like this

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Main extends MovieClip{
    private var myVertArray:Array = new Array();
    private var _box:Box = new Box();

public function Main(){
    _box.x = stage.stageWidth - _box.width;
    _box.y = stage.stageHeight - 200;
    _box.columnMaker=true; //added property
    this.addChild(_box);
    myVertArray.push(_box);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame);
}

private function onEveryFrame(ev:Event):void{
    var _myItem:Box
    for (var i:int = 0; i < myVertArray.length; i++){
        _myItem = myVertArray[i]
        _myItem.x -= 3;
        if(_myItem.x < stage.stageWidth/2 && !_myItem.passedCenter ){
            trace("myVertArray.length is : " + myVertArray.length)
            _myItem.passedCenter = true;
    if (_myItem.columnMaker) {//check added
        trace("createColumn");
        for(var j:int = 0; j < 5; j++){
            var _myNewItem:Box = new Box();
        _myNewItem.x = stage.stageWidth - 40;
        _myNewItem.y = stage.stageHeight - (_myNewItem.height * j)-
                                                 (j * 5) - _myNewItem.height /2;
        _myNewItem.alpha = 0.2;
        if (j==4) {
            _myNewItem.columnMaker=true;//give property to last object in
                                                    //columm
        }
        this.addChild(_myNewItem);
        myVertArray.push(_myNewItem);
        }
    }
        }
    }

    if(_myItem.x < 0){
        removeChild(_myItem);
        myVertArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
}
}
```